# How to implement a speech bubble on MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

This is my first question in Stackoverflow.

My question is: how to implement speech bubble control (that is used for conversation — I mean, chat) on MFC.

I want to find an easy way, rather than making a custom control from the **CScrollWnd**. Or I want to use a **Richedit** component.

Does anybody know any source code or example?

- That must embed a custom progress control.
- That must embed an OLE control (like Richedit).

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could embed a web control, and borrow from work that's already been done on CSS theming to mimic the effect:

http://www.rwe-uk.com/blog/comments/ichat_like_speech_bubbles_with_css_3/

I'd use Qt's QtWebKit, myself:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-webkit.html

It has a lot of flexibility, including embedding an arbitrary Qt Widget into a web layout and communicating with it.  That could be a progress bar, or in this example...a QTableWidget:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/webkit-webplugin.html

But I'm sure MFC has some kind of internet-explorer-embedding these days that works better than it used to.  (Okay, I'm not that sure.)

Comment: thanks for fast answer. but we need progres controll in bubble control and that must be customised so, we can't use embedding Web control

Comment: Answers on StackOverflow tend to be fast, or none at all.  :)  You can edit or tag an old question to sort of "wake it up" (with some anti-gaming strategy I'm sure).  Also, once you have some reputation points...if a question is not getting enough attention there is a "bounty system" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: @user1424923 Per your update, I updated answer to mention that if you're willing to leave clunky MFC land, I know Qt Webkit can embed arbitrary Qt widgets as a plugin.  See example.  On the plus side for Qt: open source, free, well-documented, has a nice IDE, and your programs can be compiled for Windows/Linux/Mac: http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools

Comment: i think we will use DHTML control with http://www.rwe-uk.com/blog/comments/ichat_like_speech_bubbles_with_css_3/ thnaks for answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you can use a GDI+ for that purpose. See "[Creating a Speech Balloon/Speech Bubble in GDI+](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51377/Creating-a-Speech-Balloon-Speech-Bubble-in-GDI)" on Code Project. I think it's good example, which you can further extend by adding progress bar or change balloon visualization.

Comment: Wow, that looks like a great project with awesome results!

Comment: thanks for anwser. i already saw that code. i must make custom control from CScrollWnd if i use that code but, that way is very difficult and spend long time for develop.